# laravel raw query doesn't return results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

i have the code below

```
$id = 1;
$idz = 3;
$nums = DB::select(DB::raw('select * from chat_user where user_id in (?, ?) and chat_id in (select chat_id from chat_user group by chat_id having count(*) > 1)'), array($id, $idz));
return $nums->count();
```

here i have a table named "user_chat" and i want to find out if i select two rows by their "user_id" do they have the same "chat_id". the code works fine when i test it in phpmyadmin's sql section and return the result.

```
select * from chat_user where user_id in (1, 3) and chat_id in (select chat_id from chat_user group by chat_id having count(*) > 1)
```

but when i write it in laravel's style i get this error:

```
Call to a member function count() on a non-object
```

any help would be really great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DB::select` returns an array, not an object.

Use `count($nums)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `DB::select()`, the returned thing is the result. not the query builder object.

you can tackle this in three ways.

- run another `SELECT COUNT(id)....`
- if you are selecting ALL the rows, then count the items in array.
- change it to query builder.